# Exibir conteúdo da tag <title> da página atual usando PHP

Tags: php, joomla, file-get-contents, echo, preg-match

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda para modificar o código abaixo:

```
<?php
function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp)
        return null;

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
    if (!$res)
        return null;

    // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);
    return $title;
}
```

?>

```
<?php $pagina = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

A função do código é exibir o título da página atual e este propósito está sendo executado com sucesso, porém todas páginas do site cujo o código está presente apresenta uma lentidão muito grande.

O código original foi adaptado desta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/399357/5429657.

Minha ideia ao utilizar este código é pode dar nomes a uma variável para um plugin instalado no site. Em todo artigo criado eu incluí este texto:

> {{jlexhelpful name="PARAM 1" key="content_id" section_id="2" }}

PARAM 1 representa o nome do artigo, por exemplo, Artigo 1, Artigo 2, Artigo 3... para não ter que editar este texto em todos artigos, estou usando a requisição da tag , ou seja, o 'PARAM 1' é escrito automaticamente quando o usuário visitar a página.

Tentando explicar melhor o que acontece, estou colocando nas páginas os seguintes códigos, além dos dois mencionados acima:

```
<?php echo '{{jlexhelpful name="' ?> /*Insere {{jlexhelpful name=" na página*/
<?php print page_title("$pagina"); ?> /*Está parte é responsável por imprimir o título da página atual*/
<?php echo '" key="content_99votos99" section_id="2" }}<p>' ?> /*Final do texto, complementando o conteúdo que preciso*/
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Exemplo de página com o código _lenta_ (http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br/kya).
Exemplo sem código _rápida_ (http://triviapw.hiperportal.blog.br)

Comment: Esse código faz uma requisição de URL a cada vez que é executado, e **sempre será relativamente lento**. Clique em [edit] e explique melhor o que quer obter, para que possamos propor uma alternativa mais decente, e há uma grande chance de não ser o que você precisa. O código apresentado só serve pra casos em que você não tenha acesso às páginas localmente. Aproveite para postar o código na pergunta, links externos além de poderem deixar de existir no futuro, acabam obrigando quem vai ajudar a ter que abrir uma página só pra isso, sendo que poderia estar tudo aqui.

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o cenário deste caso?

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado, tentei editei tentando detalhar melhor meu problema.

Comment: Você quer o title da própria página que o PHP está executando ou de outras? Se o joomla é seu mesmo, compensa pegar os titulos direto do seu sistema (via DB ou coisa do tipo).

Comment: @Bacco nesse caso eu usaria um javascript ou qualquer outra coisa, menus um file_get_contents.

Comment: @Bacco Gostaria que o title da própria página fosse exibido. A princípio pensei em trabalhar com o PHP apenas, pois não tenho muito conhecimento sobre programação, e com as leituras básicas que encontro pela internet, tenho melhor interpretação quando é sobre php do que consultas em banco de dados. A Instalação do Joomla é minha sim. Vou esperar mais algum tempo buscando outras alternativas, em ultimo caso retorno para o código anterior onde o php me trazia o ID do artigo em vez do Título. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, consegui resolver o problema da lentidão trocando a requisição feita pelos códigos mencionados acima da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
$ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
$article_id = $ids[0];
$article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load($article_id);
echo $article->get("title");
}
?>
```

Por fim a solução completa no meu caso foi:

```
{{jlexhelpful name="<?php
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
$ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
$article_id = $ids[0];
$article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
$article->load($article_id);
echo $article->get("title");
}
?>" key="content_<?php echo JRequest::getVar('id'); ?>" section_id="2" }}
```

Como exemplo do resultado final, aparecerá da seguinte forma:

> {{jlexhelpful name="Título do Artigo" key="content_382" section_id="2" }}

Obrigado.